# torch.cuda.is_available() returns false despite GPU being available

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pytorch, google-compute-engine, nvidia

My vm instance specs are,

```
nvcc --version

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_May__3_19:15:13_PDT_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.3, V11.3.109
```

OS Version

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
```

GPU

```
00:04.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU104GL [Tesla T4] (rev a1)
```

nvidia-smi

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

I tried running `torch.cuda.is_available()` which returns false.

Comment: Your VM instance is broken. If nvidia-smi can’t see the GPU, you don’t have a working driver

Comment: @talonmies How do I fix it? Purge nvidia and cuda libraries? Would installing nvidia-drirver with "sudo aptitude install nvidia-driver" work?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/install-drivers-gpu